Django. 'GroupDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'
I try create AddMembersForm to Group in my app.
'GroupDetailView' object has no attribute 'object'
class GroupDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Group
    context_object_name = 'group'
    template_name = 'rooms/group_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AddGroupMemberForm(group_id=self.object.id)
        context['members'] = GroupMembers.objects.filter(group=self.object) #Download all members
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AddGroupMemberForm(request.POST, group_id=self.object.id)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_member = form.save(commit=False)
            new_member.group = self.get_object()
            new_member.save()
            return redirect(self.get_object().get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Group(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='creator_group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('group_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class GroupMembers(models.Model):

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='membership')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='group_membership')
    role = models.TextField(max_length=30, default='Członek grupy')
    time_release = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} należy do {self.group.name}'

I want to add users to my groups (the group founder will have this option).

In following like you are trying to get self.object.id, your self is GroupDetailView.
form = AddGroupMemberForm(request.POST, group_id=self.object.id)
if you are sending group_id in url like /add/member/<group_id:int> then you can add following.
def post(self, request, group_id,**kwargs):
   form = AddGroupMemberForm(request.POST, group_id=group_id)


I added function get_object and pk_irl_kwarg. It working

yeah, that ll work as well.
